# Deploying multiple servlets to a single Tomcat Server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm using Eclipse and can get each of my servlets to work independently (using [HTTP Client](http://ditchnet.org/httpclient) to test) through Eclipse. But the real work is getting them to work at the same time.

I'm using Tomcat, but have no idea how to run all three servlets at the same time. They are all mapped properly in the web.xml file. How do I deploy these from Eclipse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, simply map all 3 of them in the `web.xml` and deploy them. Below, a sample `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.acme.Servlet1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.acme.Servlet2</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet3</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.acme.Servlet3</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path1/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path2/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet3</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path3/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Note that the following URLs (assuming `mycontext` is the context):

- `http://hostname:port/mycontext/path1/foo`
- `http://hostname:port/mycontext/path1/bar?aparam=avalue`
- `http://hostname:port/mycontext/path1`

Match the pattern `<url-pattern>/path1/*</url-pattern>` (so you don't need to map them on /path1, /path1/*).

If you are using Eclipse WTP, you can register Tomcat as a **Server** and deploy your **Dynamic Web Project** on it from Eclipse (**right-click** on the project and select **Run As > Run on Server**).

Outside Eclipse, you'll have to package your application as a `.war` (the standard format for a webapp) and deploy this war on Tomcat. There are several ways to do this but the most straightforward way is to copy the war into `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`.

Comment: That's awesome, and very prompt! I haven't even left the website yet!
Anyway.. thanks.. I was able to run them all from Eclipse, but will deploy them as a web-archive for Tomcat.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

if you want the servlets to be started without any request being sent to the server add 
**<load-on-startup>N<load-on-startup/>**

where **N=1,2,3....** in the **<servlet>** mapping